# How to scale a system of linear equations such that the norm of the columns of a matrix have norm 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, normed-spaces

Given matrix $A$ and vector $b$, I have a system of linear equations

$$Ax=b$$

Right now, I am reading a paper in which the author assumes that all columns of matrix $A$ have norm equal to $1$. I was wondering, if I have an arbitrary matrix $A$, how can I transform my system $Ax=b$, such that each column of $A$ has norm exactly $1$. Is this even possible if not all norms of the columns are equal?

Comment: Try to find a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A D^{-1} D  x = b$ and then let $y := D x$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. So I am at first solving $AD^{-1}y=b$ and then obtaining $x=D^{-1}y$? With your sentence 'Try to find a diagonal matrix', do you mean, that one can find an explicit description of this $D$ for a general matrix?

Comment: No, not for a general matrix. $D$ depends on $A$ and it is assumed that $A$ has no zero columns. Frankly, I do not understand what your goal is.

Comment: If I set $D_{i,i}=||A_i||$ where $A_i$ denotes the $i$-th column of the matrix $A$. Then $AD^{-1}$ has all columns with norm 1 (right?). So I can transform my system into $AD^{-1}y=b$ and then recover $x$ with $D^{-1}y$. If this is true, then I transformed my system into one where each column has norm $1$, which is exactly what I wanted

Comment: That is correct.  However, I don't understand why you want $x$. In a sense, you're merely changing the "units" used to measure distance.